# Does my Laptop motherboard has a whitelist for WIFI cards?

Tags: wireless-networking, asus-laptop, whitelist

I have a Laptop ASUS N56JR with a Qualcomm Atheros AR9485. I plan on changing it since it is kinda bad on maintaining a signal. I know for sure that some people ([On this Forum](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/opinions-on-the-n56jr.736861/page-25)) installed successfully an Intel 7260 WIFI card on the same model of Laptop that I have but I am not too happy about that card either.

Is there any chance I can install something else? Can I find out is there is indeed a whitelist of cards that I can put inside my laptop?

Comment: When you say "know for sure that some installed successfully", do you mean "some people", i.e. other users of the same computer?

Comment: Updated question for better understanding. Added the link of the forum where some users installed successfully the Wifi card in the same model of Laptop that I have.

Comment: Did you check your manual? Did you check the FAQ section for the product on manufacturer's website? If that did not answer the question for you, then you may need to try contacting them directly and asking them. Another option is to examine the firmware (BIOS or UEFI) for your computer model. That may require delinking and disassembling the code with various tools, and then rewriting it, assembling and linking it. It will require some understanding of the x86 assembly language. Of course, the easier way is to get a modified BIOS or inject a modified option ROM only that concerns WiFi.

Comment: Of course, examining the firmware is the most definite way of determining if it has a whitelist or not. But this may not even be required, if there is no such thing. You can research and see what other users (like you have done) are using, or ask the manufacturer about this. The second most reliable way to determine if any modifications to the firmware are required, or if there is a whitelist or not, is to go get a WiFi adapter of your own choice and try installing that to see if it works. Just don't get the very cheap ones from less known brands.

Comment: What's wrong with the Intel 7260? Or more importantly, what is wrong with the one you already have (Qualcomm Atheros AR9485)? (I see your updated question now, so cross out that last line.)

Comment: Atheros drops the connection like crazy. Intel is better on that. But I just wanted to know if I have other options than these two. I wanted first to check if there is more knowledge before buying and trying.

Comment: According to a user named Kevin on that forum thread you linked to, "7260 is like the best WLAN adapter you can have on the system". So why settle for less? I understand you want to know your options, but generally speaking we are living in a world where we as consumers, and as computer users have less and less options, and less control over our own devices. Dubious corporations and governments are making those choices for us, so we don't have to bother ourselves with them. It's all part of a bigger plan to "make our lives easier".

Comment: Well, that's what I wanted to find out. Do they have whitelists? If I think about a PC, you can mount almost any wireless card you would like as long as you have the right adapter. On a laptop, the wifi card is not soldered but slides in a PCI-e. That made me think that as long as I get the right size (half size) I should be able to put whatever card I want. But then my research lead me to the whitelist and I got stuck there with almost nobody being able to tell more except that in some cases the whitelist is real.

Comment: Why else do you think they have a list of allowed devices inside *our* computers? It's a *low-level* discrimination, that's what it is. The next thing you know, they want to make financial decisions for us, so we don't have to, because we as individuals are too dumb to know what's best for us. So yes, this type of lists do exist, and I hate this practice as much as any sane person would. But I'm afraid there is no way of telling for sure what you have inside that firmware unless you examine the code.

Comment: There are some user groups that focus on the art of BIOS modding. You might want to check those out. Some of them have a special sections for requesting mods. Also, please consider signing this petition for removing the whitelisting practice: https://www.bios-mods.com/welcome/2014/05/wifi-whitelist-removal-petition/

Comment: I did do a web search but it turned up empty. Except for this one: "The answer unfortunately is no. The N56JR does NOT support 5GHz and there's no BIOS whitelist." Link: https://plus.google.com/105477283453543569138/posts/9fE2RSZpSix

Comment: In other words, if you do get another adapter, make sure it is 2.4 GHz only. Or it may not work. Also, if this is all too much, consider getting a USB class WiFi adapter. Those can be had for cheap and are easy to install and there is no restriction on brand and model. More specifically, the really small "micro" adapters are ideal for laptops.

Comment: Most modern laptop bios's do have a whitelist of wifi cards, generally speaking they are only cards that were originally sold with that specific model of laptop.

Comment: You do not want the 7260, [I have it (on Asus N56JR)](https://superuser.com/questions/1332045/replacement-for-intel-dual-band-wireless-n-7260-searched?noredirect=1#comment1991499_1332045) and it does not work well. I deactivated the bluetooth, it works better now but I would not recommend anyone buying it.